# Javascript code for Drop Down List not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the following code for creating drop-down lists. The list for **Research Area** is working fine but corresponding to that research area, the second list viz **Choose Professor** which should show options like **X, Y etc.** is not appearing. What is the bug in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(s1, s2) {
      var s1 = document.getElementbyId(s1);
      var s2 = document.getElementbyId(s2);
      s2.innerHTML = "";
      if (s1.value == "Deep Learning") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Big Data") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Cryptography") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Algorithms") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Embedded Systems") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Graphic Design") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Computer Architecture") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Robotics") {
        var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
      }
      for (var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|")
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>Choose Accordingly</h2>
  <hr/> Choose Research Area:
  <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Deep Learning">Deep Learning</option>
    <option value="Big Data">Big Data</option>
    <option value="Cryptography">Cryptography</option>
    <option value="Algorithms">Algorithms</option>
    <option value="Embedded Systems">Embedded Systems</option>
    <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
    <option value="Computer Architecture">Computer Architecture</option>
    <option value="Robotics">Robotics</option>
    </select>
  <hr/> Choose Professor:
  <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
  <hr />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementbyId` should be `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo `document.getElementbyId` should be `document.getElementById` and you are populating the same values in the second dropdown no matter what you select in the first one. So there is no need of these `if` conditions

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
   var optionArray = ["|", "X|X", "Y|Y", "Z|Z", "A|A"];
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|")
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Choose Accordingly</h2>
<hr/> Choose Research Area:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Deep Learning">Deep Learning</option>
    <option value="Big Data">Big Data</option>
    <option value="Cryptography">Cryptography</option>
    <option value="Algorithms">Algorithms</option>
    <option value="Embedded Systems">Embedded Systems</option>
    <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
    <option value="Computer Architecture">Computer Architecture</option>
    <option value="Robotics">Robotics</option>
    </select>
<hr/> Choose Professor:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
<hr />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use...
        s2.appendChild(newOption);
Instead of
        s2.options.add(newOption);